# mv vs cp: what is different about the resulting file?

Tags: linux, bash

I had a bug where a configuration file for some application was not being included properly, so to try to isolate the problematic line of the file, I copied the old contents into a new file a few lines at a time.

By the end, I had made an exact duplicate of the file but the old one still would not work whereas the new one worked perfectly fine.

More to the point, if I use the `mv` command to move the file from where I have it stored into the place it wants to be, it causes errors. If I use `cp` to copy the file into the place it wants to be, there are no errors.

Obviously, stuff like `diff`, `file`, or `ls -l`, reveal no differences between the two files because one is a copy of the other, **insofar as `cp` makes an exact copy of the file**.

I can't share too much information about the file because this is a work thing. The bottom line is that the commands `cp fileA fileB` and `mv fileA fileB` produce a "different" fileB. My best guess is some super low-level attribute from fileB is left behind during `cp` (even `cp -p` produces the same behaviour).

What does mv do differently than cp, pertaining to the exact contents of the resulting file?

EDIT: With `ls -l`:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3389 Aug  8 22:53 fileA
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3389 Aug  8 23:03 fileB
```

EDIT: The application is mysql and the file is a .cnf file and the item in this configuration file that was specifically of interest is the name of the binary log used in master-slave database replication. The "error" is "you are not using binary logging" because there is no binary log because that item was never "read" by mysql.

My initial thought was that there was a syntax error in the configuration file which was causing the whole thing to not get read, which is what lead me to manually recreating it by copying blocks of text

EDIT: Getting somewhere... Finally something different about the files.

`ls -lZ`

```
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 server.cnf.bad
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:mysqld_etc_t:s0 server.cnf.good
```

Comment: Have you checked the file ownership?

Comment: Do you run `cp -p` as a regular user? See [*Why can't a normal user `chown` a file?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27350/108618) In general, unless you're root, `cp -p` won't preserve ownership; `mv` will.

Comment: all the `mv` and `cp` (and `vim` for that matter) are done as sudo

Comment: What about `cp -a` instead of `cp -p`?

Comment: The file resulting from `cp -a badFile` works properly, so whatever is broken doesn't carry over with `cp -a` either.

Comment: What does "not being included properly" mean?  It might help if you said exactly what goes wrong with the original.

Comment: with SELinux (mostly default on RHEL and derivatives), even context has to be checked: `ls -lZ`

Comment: @A.B you should write it as an answer

Comment: I'll do. I won the "test this" lottery.

Comment: Also for @AndrewPearce that's why you shouldn't omit context in the question. `fileA` can't give a hint, `server.cnf` would help more, telling it's about `mysqld` not starting after changes to its configuration file, this on Linux distribution XYZ, even better.

Comment: Good to know. This didn't seem like a mysql problem. I thought mysql was exposing weird behaviour in the filesystem. Lesson learned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: in a system where [SELinux](https://selinuxproject.org/) is in use, files used by the system (ie: daemons) should be copied or moved around with `cp -aZ` and `mv -Z` instead of `cp -a` and `mv`. If this wasn't done, one should just use `restorecon -v -r` or `restorecon -v -F -r` on the destination to ask the system to restore default SELinux contexts. It's always a good idea to use [`restorecon`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/policycoreutils/restorecon.8.en.html) at the end of a script that worked on key configuration files.

RHEL and thus most of its derivatives [use SELinux by default](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Packages).

So to solve your problem, if your system is RHEL based and using the `mariadb-server` package, just do at the final step when the file is at the *correct place*:

```
# restorecon -v -F /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf
Relabeled /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf from unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 to system_u:object_r:mysqld_etc_t:s0
```

(Note that without `-F` it wouldn't change `unconfined_u` to the configured `system_u`. It wouldn't matter for common systems. My knowledge of the difference and why it doesn't matter doesn't go this far).

It would be just more work to put the correct context on the file in an *other* place. [`chcon`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/coreutils/chcon.1.en.html) can do this (either by stating it with `-u` `-t` etc., more simply by copying the context from an other file with `--reference`):

```
# ls -lZ /home/test/server.cnf.bad
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 744 Apr 30  2017 /home/test/server.cnf.bad
# chcon -v -u system_u -t mysqld_etc_t /home/test/server.cnf.bad 
changing security context of '/home/test/server.cnf.bad'
# ls -lZ /home/test/server.cnf.bad
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:mysqld_etc_t:s0 744 Apr 30  2017 /home/test/server.cnf.bad
```

If you suspect SELinux issues, check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for entries with the word `denied` related to your process or file. You can always temporarily ask SELinux to allow operations, and then restore them, with respectively `setenforce Permissive` and `setenforce Enforcing` to compare behaviour. Don't leave it at `Permissive` especially for production.

Various explanations following...

### Example and what should be done when working on configuration files

Example of bahaviour with various `cp` options and `mv` on a SELinux enabled system:

```
$ id
uid=1034(test) gid=1034(test) groups=1034(test)
$ pwd
/home/test
test@glasswalker:~$ ls -lZ foo
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 0 Aug 11 11:25 foo
$ cp foo /tmp/foo1
$ cp --preserve=context foo /tmp/foo2
$ cp -a foo /tmp/foo3
$ cp -aZ foo /tmp/foo4
$ mv foo /tmp/foo5
$ ls -lZ /tmp/foo?
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmpfs_t:s0 0 Aug 11 11:25 /tmp/foo1
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0  0 Aug 11 11:25 /tmp/foo2
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0  0 Aug 11 11:25 /tmp/foo3
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmpfs_t:s0 0 Aug 11 11:25 /tmp/foo4
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0  0 Aug 11 11:25 /tmp/foo5
$ touch bar
$ ls -lZ bar
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 0 Aug 11 11:49 bar
$ mv -Z bar /tmp
$ ls -lZ /tmp/bar
-rw-r--r--. 1 test test unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmpfs_t:s0 0 Aug 11 11:49 /tmp/bar
```

So using `cp -aZ` or `mv -Z` works fine when security contexts do matter and still preserves other attributes. A script moving system files around should always use the `-Z` option for any `cp` or `mv` command, or else just use `restorecon` in its final step to avoid unexpected issues.

### Why those differences?

The `mv` command keeps a consistent behaviour. If it happened in the same filesystem, of course anything attached to a file, including its security context, wouldn't be altered since it's just a "rename". So across two filesystems, where it's actually a copy then delete, it also copies over unchanged whatever is attached to the file and it knows about, including its security context, for consistency.

The `cp` command by default just *creates* a new file, so this file inherits the parent's selinux context as usual, unless of course told otherwise with `--preserve=context` which is included in `-a`. `--preserve=context` can be susbtracted from `-a` with the option `-Z` so the best bet when copying whole arborescences is to use `-aZ` instead of `-a` if SELinux does matter.

By default when creating a file, which is the usual case, this new file inherits its directory SELinux context, that's why everything works fine (off-topic: in the rare case the file context should be different from its directory's context just because of a rule on its name, the kernel won't care, programs like the daemon [`restorecond`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/restorecond/restorecond.8.en.html) will be needed to handle it).

### What is SELinux

SELinux is a mandatory access control mechanism (aka [MAC](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/selg-overview#sec-mac-intro1)) used in addition to all other mechanisms (unix permissions aka [DAC](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/selg-overview#sec-dac-intro1), Access control lists aka [ACL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/selg-overview#sec-acl-intro1) etc.). When a process runs in a process security context, there's a "rules matrix" to check if this *process* context can do the asked operation (open, read, write, mmap,...)  on the *file* context it tries to work on.

Example for OP's case: If the `mysqld`'s process context is only allowed to access a few file context types, including `mysqld_etc_t` but not `user_home_t` then starting `mysqld` will fail because it couldn't read its configuration file with the wrong `user_home_t` type.

On usual systems, this doesn't matter for the interactive/logged-in user, because its usual process context is unconfined, meaning no SELinux rule will apply. Every daemon started by `systemd` or other similar mechanisms *will* receive a process context, which can be checked with `ps`'s `-Z` option. Example on a Debian system running SELinux:

```
# ps -Z -p $$
LABEL                             PID TTY          TIME CMD
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 22498 pts/7 00:00:00 bash
# ps -Z -p $(pidof /sbin/getty)
LABEL                             PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
system_u:system_r:getty_t:s0     6158 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty1
system_u:system_r:getty_t:s0     6159 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty2
system_u:system_r:getty_t:s0     6160 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty3
system_u:system_r:getty_t:s0     6161 tty4     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty4
system_u:system_r:getty_t:s0     6162 tty5     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty5
system_u:system_r:getty_t:s0     6163 tty6     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty 38400 tty6
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a principal difference:

- cp makes a copy of the file
- mv (if you stay within the filesystem) just moves some pointers on the disk.

Try the following:

```
touch a
ls -i a
cp a b
ls -i a b
mv a c
ls -i b c
```

You will see that b is a new file with a new inode number, where as c is just the same file with the inode number of the old a.

Still, that does not explain your strange behaviour.

Comment: I had thought about the inode pointers as well, but if anything is corrupted in there, `cp` should either not work properly, or copy the broken stuff too.

Comment: I would expect `cp` to create an entirely new inode, using only the destination name/path. keep in mind, there are many ways the code for these features could be implemented. I'm sure for instance that cp calls a kernel method, passing parameters. those params may or may not come from or be read from the inode, and its possible that anti-corruption code was added on one end or the other, or only for a particular argument, or whatever, so we can't really make any serious assumptions about the issue other than that you have an inode corruption, and cp fixed it by creating a new inode.

Answer (score 3):

This is what *may* be happening (you share very little information about the application or these errors, so I can only guess).

In Linux [mandatory file locking is uncommon](https://gavv.github.io/blog/file-locks/#mandatory-locking). Calls like [`flock(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) manage *advisory* locks. This means the kernel keeps track of locks but doesn't enforce them, it's up to applications to obey them.

If something locks `fileA` and your application obeys the lock, it may refuse service. Let's assume this is what happens.

The lock affects inode rather than path or name. Moving (renaming) the locked `fileA` to `fileB` within a single filesystem does nothing to the inode, the file is still locked, the application still refuses to work with it. Copying the file creates a separate `fileB` with its own inode which is not locked, the application works.

(Note: moving a file to another filesystem is in fact copying+deleting, so it should break the lock, if any).

Comment: The specific application is mysql and I'm concerning myself with a .cnf file. The specific line is log-bin=file-bin.log, and mysql was not making the binary logs correctly (thus breaking all the master-slave stuff). I'll see if mysql does any file locking stuff.